# Why boolean expressions only operate against scalars?

Tags: syntax, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I've never seen a language that supports a syntax for boolean operators like this:

```
if (birdType == ('hummingbird' || 'robin')) {
    ...
}
```

You have to construct the `if` statement like this, instead:

```
if (birdType == 'hummingbird' || birdType == 'robin') {
    ...
}
```

Is there a reason for this? Is this somehow impossible or exceedingly complicated to support?

Comment: One reason is that it goes against the theoretical framework, propositional logic, where each expression is evaluated to true or false. Another reason is that it's trivial to implement a function which supports this (i.e. "eqAny(birdType, "hummingbird, "robin")". However, you can't implement short-circuiting this function easily in Java without passing in something like a lambda to those functions "eqAny(birdType, {}->"hummingbird", {}->"robin")", but u probably don't need the short-circuiting requirement. However, in a lazy language, you can implement "eqAny" without passing in lambdas.

Comment: Also your proposed syntax creates ambiguities like "a == (b || c)". Does this mean "((a == b) || (a == c))"? Or does it mean "(a == (b || c))". Unless you overloaded the || operator to return different types (like a list of values for non-boolean operands, and overloaded the == operator to behave differently on lists than other data types... Yeah this is just too weird.